# WPF set selected item in listview when combobox is selected

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have the following `listview`:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Transducers}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTransducer}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="ID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LabID}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Manufacturer" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Manufacturer}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Channel">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Channels, ElementName=mainInterface}" 
                                  SelectedItem="{Binding Channel, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                  SelectedValue="{Binding Channel.ID}"
                                  SelectedValuePath="ID"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

It has a few text items and a combobox. After I change the combobox value, I want to do something to the selected item, which should be the item whose combobox is just interacted with. However, when I interact with the combobox on the item and nothing else with item, it does not become selected. How do I set the selected item when I interact with the combobox of that item?

Comment: What you describe is the default behavior of the wpf DataGrid control. This control is also better suited for editing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filippo's solution was close but did not work in my case. I ended up using the `TryFindParent<T>()` function he mentioned, but my code looked like this:

```
private void ComboBox_DropDownClosed(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    listView.SelectedItem = null;
    var newSelectedItem = (sender as ComboBox).TryFindParent<ListViewItem>();         
    newSelectedItem.IsSelected = true;
}
```

where `listView` is the name of my ListView.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
(sender as ComboBox).TryFindParent<ListView>().SelectedItem = (sender as ComboBox).TryFindParent<ListViewItem>();
```

on your dropDownClosed event

`TryFindParent<T>()` is a helper function found here: http://www.hardcodet.net/2008/02/find-wpf-parent

```
/// <summary>
/// Finds a parent of a given item on the visual tree.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type of the queried item.</typeparam>
/// <param name="child">A direct or indirect child of the
/// queried item.</param>
/// <returns>The first parent item that matches the submitted
/// type parameter. If not matching item can be found, a null
/// reference is being returned.</returns>
public static T TryFindParent<T>(this DependencyObject child)
    where T : DependencyObject
{
  //get parent item
  DependencyObject parentObject = GetParentObject(child);

  //we've reached the end of the tree
  if (parentObject == null) return null;

  //check if the parent matches the type we're looking for
  T parent = parentObject as T;
  if (parent != null)
  {
    return parent;
  }
  else
  {
    //use recursion to proceed with next level
    return TryFindParent<T>(parentObject);
  }
}

/// <summary>
/// This method is an alternative to WPF's
/// <see cref="VisualTreeHelper.GetParent"/> method, which also
/// supports content elements. Keep in mind that for content element,
/// this method falls back to the logical tree of the element!
/// </summary>
/// <param name="child">The item to be processed.</param>
/// <returns>The submitted item's parent, if available. Otherwise
/// null.</returns>
public static DependencyObject GetParentObject(this DependencyObject child)
{
  if (child == null) return null;

  //handle content elements separately
  ContentElement contentElement = child as ContentElement;
  if (contentElement != null)
  {
    DependencyObject parent = ContentOperations.GetParent(contentElement);
    if (parent != null) return parent;

    FrameworkContentElement fce = contentElement as FrameworkContentElement;
    return fce != null ? fce.Parent : null;
  }

  //also try searching for parent in framework elements (such as DockPanel, etc)
  FrameworkElement frameworkElement = child as FrameworkElement;
  if (frameworkElement != null)
  {
    DependencyObject parent = frameworkElement.Parent;
    if (parent != null) return parent;
  }

  //if it's not a ContentElement/FrameworkElement, rely on VisualTreeHelper
  return VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);
}
```

Comment: What is `TryFindParent`? Is this an external function I need to get from somewhere?